# How to overwrite values after grouping but preserving the initial value for the group

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to do a simple overwriting in R, but I guess is not as simple as I thought it would be.
I have a `beginning`, an `end`, a `majorCategory` and a `subCategory`. For every `majorCategory`, there is a `beginning` and an `end`. I have the length of the `majorCategory`  and I calculate the length of the `subcategories`, and from now on I am stuck because I would like to overwrite the beginnings and the ends for the subcategories but at the same time preserve the initial beginnings for the `majorCategory` . How do I do that?

```
 df <- structure(list(majorCat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L), .Label = c("Major_A", "Major_B"), class = "factor"), begin = c(60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60,60,60, 
 60, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), end = c(75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80), subCat 
 = c("d", "b", "c", "e", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "b", "d", "b", "d", "e", "b")), row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "data.frame")


  library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
     group_by(begin, end, subCat) %>% 
     summarise(countt = n()) %>% 
     mutate(percc = countt/sum(countt),
     lengthh = end - begin,
     lengthhSubCat = lengthh * percc) %>% select(begin, end, lengthh , lengthhSubCat)
```

[image]

I would very much like to get to this:
[image]

Thank you very very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the columns, create a new group by `paste`ing the 'begin', 'end' ('grp'), concatenate the `first` element of 'begin' with the last element removed from 'lengthhSubCat', do a cumulative sum to create the 'begin' column, while we take the `lead` of 'begin' and fill the `last` observation with the corresponding value of 'end' to update the 'end' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   group_by(begin, end, subCat) %>%
   summarise(countt = n()) %>%
   mutate(percc = countt/sum(countt),
         lengthh = end - begin,
         lengthhSubCat = lengthh * percc) %>% 
   group_by(grp = str_c(begin, end, sep="_")) %>% 
   mutate(begin = cumsum(c(first(begin), lengthhSubCat[-n()])),
         end = lead(begin, default = last(end))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(begin, end, lengthh, lengthhSubCat)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  begin   end lengthh lengthhSubCat
#  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>
#1  20    44        60          24  
#2  44    68        60          24  
#3  68    80        60          12  
#4  60    63        15           3  
#5  63    67.5      15           4.5
#6  67.5  69        15           1.5
#7  69    72        15           3  
#8  72    75        15           3
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you very much for posting. Do you think you have a typo because I don't get the expected result? and there are 2 Major Categories, Major_A starts begins at 60 and ends at 75 and Major_B starts at 60 and ends at 75.

Comment: You are the best! :) Thank you very much. :) it is even annoying, I spend the better part of the day trying different approaches searching in SO for some inspiration and you did it for a few minutes. :) Thank you!

Comment: @eyei Sorry, I didn't notice the last grouping.  Updated. thanks